# Does re-using HttpClient with simultaneous requests cause them to queue up?

Tags: c#, task

I'm writing a responsive API. We have to handle 10 requests per second.

The problem is, sending a response takes half a second. So you can imagine, the server is overwhelmed quickly.

I made the code process asynchronously, up to 10 tasks at once, to help mitigate this.

However I have concerns about whether using a single instance of `HttpClient` is the correct approach. The advice as soon as someone mentions `HttpClient` is always create a single instance of it.

I have a static instance of it. Although it is thread-safe, at least for `PostAsync`, should I really create 10 HttpClients (or a pool of HttpClients) to be able to send data out faster?

I assume that during the half a second it's sending out, that it won't let you send out other 'postasync's. However I can't confirm this behaviour.

Most benchmarks and resources simply look at sending requests synchronously, i.e. one after the other (i.e. `await postasync`)

However for my use case I need to send several simultaneously, i.e. from separate threads. The only way to reply to 10 messages per second that take half a second each is to to send five simultanous messages back - not five queued to go out one by one, but five simultaneous messages.

I cannot find any documentation on how `HttpClient` handles this. I've only seen a few references to it having a connection pool, but it's unclear whether it will actually perform multiple connections simultaneously, or if I need to create a small pool of 5 httpclients to rotate through.

**Question: Does a single instance of HttpClient support multiple connections simultaneously?**

And I don't mean just letting you call postasync lots of times in a thread-safe way before it has finished, but I mean truly opening five simultaneous connections and sending data through each of them at the exact same time?

An example would be, you're sending fifty 10 byte files to the moon, and there is a latency of 10 seconds. Your program scoops up all fifty files and makes fifty calls to HttpClient.PostAsync almost instantly.

Assuming the listening service can support it, would the cross-thread calls to HttpClient.PostAsync open fifty connections (or whatever, some limit, but more than 1) and send the data, meaning that the server receives all fifty files ~10 seconds later?

Or would it internally queue them up and you'd end up waiting 10x50=500 seconds?

Comment: Required reading for anyone using HttpClient: [You're using httpclient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) and also [You're (probably still) using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/).

Comment: For those reasons, I prefer to use [Flurl](https://flurl.dev/) for consuming HTTP resources.

Comment: Take a read of this for some helpful background: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/330364/should-we-create-a-new-single-instance-of-httpclient-for-all-requests

Comment: Have read the arguments for using a single instance, but many examples and performance tests are testing a loop of requests one after the other, whereas my use case is multithreaded simultaneous connections.

Comment: Have clarified my question as someone voted to close as too many questions. @mason flurl under the hood uses a single `HttpClient` instance.

Comment: So? The point is Flurl devs have solved a lot of the issues. If you have concerns about a single instance, then test HttpClient to see if your concerns are valid or not.

Answer (score 2):

> However I can't confirm this behaviour.

Why not? Just create a webapi with a few seconds delay, and test calling it with `HttpClient`. Or you can use a service like [Slowwly](http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/).

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    await Serial(stopwatch);
    Console.WriteLine($"Serial took {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
    stopwatch.Restart();
    await Concurrent(stopwatch);
    Console.WriteLine($"Concurrent took {stopwatch.Elapsed}");
}

private static async Task Serial(Stopwatch stopwatch)
{
    for (var i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        await MakeRequest(stopwatch, client);
    }
}

private static async Task Concurrent(Stopwatch stopwatch)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 5).Select(async _ => { await MakeRequest(stopwatch, client); }).ToList();
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private static async Task MakeRequest(Stopwatch stopwatch, HttpClient client)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.Elapsed}: Issuing request.");
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/3000/url/http://www.google.com");
    Console.WriteLine($"{stopwatch.Elapsed}: Received {response.Length} bytes.");
}
```

Output for me (from the US):

```
00:00:00.0463664: Issuing request.
00:00:04.2560734: Received 49237 bytes.
00:00:04.2562498: Issuing request.
00:00:07.6731908: Received 49247 bytes.
00:00:07.6734158: Issuing request.
00:00:11.0882322: Received 49364 bytes.
00:00:11.0883803: Issuing request.
00:00:14.4990981: Received 49294 bytes.
00:00:14.4993977: Issuing request.
00:00:17.9082167: Received 49328 bytes.
Serial took 00:00:17.9083969
00:00:00.0025096: Issuing request.
00:00:00.0252402: Issuing request.
00:00:00.0422682: Issuing request.
00:00:00.0588887: Issuing request.
00:00:00.0755351: Issuing request.
00:00:03.4631815: Received 49278 bytes.
00:00:03.4632073: Received 49293 bytes.
00:00:03.4844698: Received 49313 bytes.
00:00:03.4913929: Received 49308 bytes.
00:00:03.4915415: Received 49280 bytes.
Concurrent took 00:00:03.4917199
```

> Question: Does a single instance of HttpClient support multiple connections simultaneously?

Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no limit, or at least, it's a high one.

I made a default web api application, modified the boilerplate controller method to this:

```
// GET api/values
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
{
    Debug.Print("Called");
    Thread.Sleep(100000);
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

I then made a program that using a single instance of HttpClient, would make lots of simultaneous connections using `Task.Run`.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

var task1 = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var task2 = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var task3 = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var task4 = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var task5 = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var task6 = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var task7 = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var task8 = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var task9 = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var taskA = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var taskB = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var taskC = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var taskD = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));
var taskE = Task.Run(() => httpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:57984/api/values"));


await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2, task3, task4, task5, task6, task7, task8, task9, taskA, taskB, taskC, taskD);
```

I ran them and the word 'Called' was logged 14 times.

Since the Thread.Sleep will have blocked the response, it *should* mean there were 14 simultaneous connections.

There are two properties that might affect the maximum number of connections, that I've found by looking on google:

`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit` which is defaulted to 2

and, the `HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer` which is also 2.

As I'm able to make many more than 2 connections, I really don't know if it's just ignored, or if these are the wrong settings, or what. Changing them appears to have no effect.

I noticed after a lot of stopping and starting my test projects that new connections were much slower to be made. I am guessing that I saturated the connection pool.

My conclusion is that if you set those two values to something higher (just in case, I mean, why not), then you can use a single httpclient concurrently where the connections will be truly concurrent, rather than sequential and thread safe.